# adding a node in the list doesnt work properly

Tags: c, list, pointers

i know ure done with my non functioning functions but i really need help,
when i enter a list head here i expect its adress to change to the tail adress but it doesnt
here is my function
and below it ure gonna find the main where i call the function
i really appreciate your help. thank you a lot

```
void add_employee(list *node)
{
    list *tail = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));

    printf("adress of node %p\n", tail);
    printf("Adding employee\n");

    printf("\t- First name :\t");
    scanf("%10s", tail->e.firstname);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\t- Last name  :\t");
    scanf("%10s", tail->e.lastname);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\t- Salary     :\t");
    scanf("%lf", &tail->e.salary);
    fflush(stdin);

    tail->next = NULL;
    node = tail;

    printf("continue ? (Y/n) : ");

    if (toupper(getchar()) == 'Y')
        add_employee(tail->next);
}
```

here is the main.c file\

ps : i know that display should take the head and if add_employee works properly myList is gonna be the tail but that is to be modified later for now i just need to know why is add_employee not working properly

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "myFunctionsLists.h"

void main()
{
    list *myList = NULL;

    char choice = 'Q';
    do
    {
        choice = menu();
        empty_buffer();

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            printf("adress %p\n", myList);
            add_employee(myList);
            printf("adress %p\n", myList);
            break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            display_list(myList);
            break;
        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
            printf("quitting...");
            free_list(myList);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unknown choice\n");
            break;
        }
        empty_buffer();
    } while (1);
}
```

Comment: parameters are passed by value. Pointers are no exception. If you want to modify the parameter pass it by reference

Comment: uh wait. This is C not C++. Please dont spam tags. C and C++ are two different languages

Comment: C does not have references, but you can pass a `list**`

Comment: it worked thank you so much. and sorry thought that c and c++ are similar so c++ people could help. ( and i was right )

Comment: actually C and C++ are very different. I can say with confidence that I don't know much about C and usually I stay away from C questions. This just happens to be a very frequent question also about C++ code where you would use a `list*&`